# JSONError: Error: Unable to initialize main class com.sort.BubbleSort Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, sorting

Here is the code (java), and I am using VSCode :

```
package com.sort;

import org.json.simple.*;

public class BubbleSort {

  private static int count = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName =
      "C:/Users/Sid/Desktop/code/cis055/cupcake/src/main/java/com/sort/cupcake_3906.json";
    
    // read cupcake names
    JSONArray cupcakeArray = JSONFile.readArray(fileName);
    String[] cupcakeNameArray = nameArray(cupcakeArray);
    System.out.println(cupcakeNameArray);

    // print unsorted list
    System.out.println("----- Unsorted array -----");
    print(cupcakeNameArray);

    // sort
    bubbleSort(cupcakeNameArray);

    // print sorted list
    System.out.println("----- Sorted array----- ");
    print(cupcakeNameArray);

    // print statistics
    System.out.println("----- Statistics -----");
    System.out.printf("Size of array = %d\n", cupcakeNameArray.length);
    System.out.printf("Count = %d\n", count);
  }

  // print cupcake array
  public static void print(String[] cupcakeNameArray) {
    System.out.printf("Number\tName\n");
    System.out.printf("------\t---------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < cupcakeNameArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.printf("%04d\t%s\n", i, cupcakeNameArray[i]);
    }
  }

  // get array of cupcake names
  public static String[] nameArray(JSONArray cupcakeArray) {
    String[] arr = new String[cupcakeArray.size()];

    // get names from json object
    for (int i = 0; i < cupcakeArray.size(); i++) {
      JSONObject o = (JSONObject) cupcakeArray.get(i);
      String name = (String) o.get("name");
      arr[i] = name;
    }
    return arr;
  }

  // bubble sort array, O(n^2), unoptimized brute force solution
  public static void bubbleSort(String[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (j + 1 < arr.length) {
          if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[j + 1]) > 0) {
            swap(arr, j, j + 1);
          }
        }
        // increase count
        count++;
      }
    }
  }

  // swap
  public static void swap(String[] arr, int a, int b) {
    String temp;
    temp = arr[a];
    arr[a] = arr[b];
    arr[b] = temp;
  }
}
```

Whenever I run my code, I keep receiving this error:

Error: Unable to initialize main class com.sort.BubbleSort
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JSONArray

To be clear, I have added the proper dependencies in my pom.xml file, and I cannot figure out why this error is happening. Please help!!
[screenshot of my pom.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFGjV.png)

Comment: Does your vscode have maven support? Or does it recognize the pom in any way?

Comment: The error occurs because the json-simple JAR file is not in the classpath when you're running your code, hence the JVM is unable to load the class files from the JAR file, such as the JSONArray class. This leads to a NoClassDefFoundError. To fix it you need to ensure that the json-simple JAR file is present in your classpath when you run your app.